# How to prevent VLC from closing when paused for around 5 hour

Tags: music-player, vlc

At the moment, I use the VLC application for my music on my cellphone. Recently, they pushed out an update that moved everyone away from the beta application to the normal one.

Since this update, I'm noticing the fact that the application shuts down after you pause the music for around 4-5 hours.

This behavior ready broke my workflow, where before I only had to plug in my audio cable, I now need to plugin my cable, unlock my phone, open VLC, manually add every audio file in my files, and then turn on shuffle, before I can enjoy my music 2 times a day.

How do I make VLC stay active during periods of inactivity?

Comment: The kernel is probably force closing it due to inactivity and needed to free up RAM for other activities... This is normal Android behavior. Why can't you just use a playlist?

Comment: I never experienced this behaviour when using the Beta of vlc, and I basically didn't use my phone during the 4-5 hour period (I'm either on my work or at sleep)

Comment: @Ferrybig: Enable ADB on your device and read out the `logcat` after you experience another VLC close. May be VLC was closed because of a n exception - you will see that in the logcat. If it is a bug of VLC you can post the VLC stacktrace in the VLC bugtracker.

Comment: The Android doesn't kill a foreground process. The VLC keep the notification to grant it's running as a foreground process.
Or it's a memory issue, or it's a crash, or it's a VLC feature.
I think Android won't kill it.

Try to report it to VLC team.
https://github.com/videolan/vlc-android
It's the best starter point.

And try to capture the log, if it's not a feature, they'll ask it to you.

Comment: @Robert `logcat` produces large amounts of data for me, is there a way to filter to out of memory errors, after I capture for example 4 hours of data? I have the feeling it is memory related, as opposed to error related, as opening Google maps always causes VLC to close, unless its laying music

Comment: [Filter LogCat to get only the messages from My Application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I have installed to VLC v3.0.5 on Android 7 and have not had a problem thus far. It could be an Android specific problem or networking if you use streaming media. I only playback music and do not watch videos or internet streams on VLC. Here is how I went about with the updated VLC.

In existing install of VLC. Go to phone's setting and choose App. Choose to clear cache and clear data. Then uninstall.

Install VLC from Play Store. At installation, give it time during parsing media stage (monitor the progress window), if anything interrupts it then you will have to manually add media files. Takes me just over 3 minutes to clear parsing media stage.

Allow permission to

**Photos, media and files on your device**

**Draw Over Other Apps**

add device SD card to medialibrary

Hope this helps.
The only permission I did not give it is, 
Allow write system settings.